# How to modify the comment body while in comment.tpl.php

Tags: 7, comments

At a Drupal 7 website dedicated to a card game I'm trying to color the special characters for hearts and diamonds [in all plain_text comments](http://preferans.de/comment/1422#comment-1422) red.

Since I haven't found the way [to modify the text filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74322/how-to-install-a-text-filter-for-plain-text-input-format) yet, I'm trying to "hack" the file **themes/bartik/templates/comment.tpl.php** as workaround by inserting the 5 lines below:

```
<div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
  <?php
    // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['links']);

    $body = $comment->comment_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $body =  str_replace('♦', '<font color="red">♦</font>', $body);
    $body =  str_replace('♥', '<font color="red">♥</font>', $body);
    print "\n<!--\n" . $body . "\n-->\n";
    $comment->comment_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $body;

    print render($content);
  ?>
```

In the HTML comment between `<!--` and `-->` above I can see that the string substitution has worked okay.

But the comment itself isn't modified.

I've tried modifying both `$comment->comment_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` and `$comment->comment_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value']` but the comment is still unchanged.

I've studied the output of `print_r($content)` and `var_dump($content)` but still can't figure out how to modify the comment body.

Comment: You are altering $comment, but rendering $content. That's 2 different variables, so no surprise it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist, you can always go like that:

```
 print str_replace(
   array('♦','♥'),
   array('<font color="red">♦</font>', '<font color="red">♥</font>'),
   render($content)
 );
```

But instead of deprecated `<font>`, use `<span class="">` and CSS. Consider classes for all 4 colours, for black and red, and for card marks altogether, for future styling ease.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually considering CSS classes - but unfortunately not sure, in which file to put them

Comment: `custom.css`, and then in yourtemplate.info add a line `stylesheets[all][] = custom.css`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you don't modify the comment in the template file because that is not what the template file is for.
It is for changing the way content displays, not changing the content itself.

One step better is to use the preprocessor function:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  // Modify the variables here, before they get printed in the template.
  // The content that prints out is in $variables['content'].
}
```

However that isn't ideal either.

I would say the best solution would involve a custom module.

You can use [hook_comment_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view/7) to modify the $comment variable like this:

```
function MODULENAME_comment_view($comment, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // Modify the $comment variable here.
}
```

Comment: Note OP only wanted to do this as a quick fix before he can [achieve it using text filters](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74322/how-to-install-a-text-filter-for-plain-text-input-format). So, OP already knew what the proper way is, and all he needed here was quick and dirty hack for the meantime.

Comment: Still, implementing a quick workaround doesn't have to mean doing things improperly. And it's good for other people who might end up finding this to know the preferable alternatives.